# Scala Capture Expression Name without a Macro

Tags: scala, macros

I'm trying to grab the name of an expression call without using a macro. I have the following example code:

```
case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
case class MyClass[T]() {
    def doSomething(value: Any)
}
val p = Person("Bob",40)
val my = MyClass[Person]
my.doSomething(p.name)
my.doSomething(p.age)
```

Is there a simple way inside the method `doSomething` to capture the expression name being used when making the call, for example capture a `String` value of `name` and `age`?

I know if I turn `doSomething` into a macro the passed parameter is an `Expr` of `Context` and I can get the name using the `Tree` of the `Expr`, however given the complex nature of macros I'm sort of thing to avoid using one in this case.

Comment: This is by nature a reflection-y thing to do, and a kind of reflection that can happen at compile-time. Also your types don't line up—`my.doSomething` can only take a `person`.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is no.  There is currently no way of getting an abstract syntax tree (AST) except with macros.

You could use `reify` here with some success, but that itself is a macro, and this would require the `doSomething` caller to have to use `reify`, which is strange.  For example, in the following code `doSomething` returns the property name together with the value of the property for the instance passed to the case class constructor:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import scala.reflect.runtime._ 
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox

case class Person(name: String, age: Int)
case class MyClass[T](t: T) {
    val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
    def doSomething[U](expr: Expr[T => U]) = Some(expr.tree) collect {
        case f@Function(_, Select(_, property)) => 
            val func = tb.eval(f).asInstanceOf[T => U]
            property.decoded -> func(t)
    }
}
```

Which can be called as:

```
val p = Person("Bob",40)
val my = MyClass(p)
//The caller needs to use reify, which is strange!
my.doSomething(reify((_:Person).name)) //Some(("name", "Bob"))
my.doSomething(reify { (p:Person) => p.age }) //Some(("age",40))
```

But this is fragile and error prone, and at this point you might as well write a macro!

Your other option is to pass in a `String` name of the property and use reflection to get that property from the instance.

You can look at the docs for [`Trees`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/symbols-trees-types.html) and [`macros`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html) to learn more.